# How to Specify Default Registry Settings for Project Centennial

Tags: desktop-bridge

I'm trying to manually build my own appx with makeappx.exe and my own appmanifest.xml. Everything has gone great, except for two issues. This is the first:

Our app requires registry settings to force the embedded browser to use IE 11. I have a .reg that has these in it, but I can't figure out how to include these in the package like the Store Mappings file does for files.

So how does one add default registry settings for an app going to the store?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious and easy answer would be to write the registry keys on the first launch of the application.

Apart from that, I know that the desktop app converter creates a 'registry.dat' file that contains the registry entries modified by the installer. At runtime this file then gets combined with the real registry to create a virtual registry without modifying the real registry. All writes to the registry get stored in this file. Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes

I'm not sure how exactly that file works and how it is loaded. But I would guess if you can create a registry.dat file and pack it in the .appx it might work?